# How to access Android HTTPS rest webservices which are windows authenticated

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myXPu.png)i have a url , on executing on browser a pop up dialogue comes which asks for username and password , and after entering username and password i get the json response . i'm not able able to do the same from android app . in ios its attained by using "authenticationchallenge" method . is there any method in android for such authentication . below is the code i use

```
try{

 URL url = new URL(reqUrl);

            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            SSLContext sc;

            sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

          
  sc.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());

            conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

            String userpass = "username" + ":" + "password";

            String basicAuth = "Basic " +Base64.encodeToString(userpass.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);

            
          conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
           
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } 


      catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }
```

i get the below in logcat
Server responded with: 401

I/O Exception

attached image is the dialogue i get .how to perform authentication for this from my android app ?
Thanks for your help .

Comment: Are you sure this is a "GET" method webservice...? The username and password of the entity(whose details you are trying to access) should be submitted(or sent) with the webservice request ...? So it must be a "POST" webservice. Besides "GET" method is rarely(mostly never) used to pass username and password to webservices...

Comment: Yes it is "GET" method . and url is username password protected. have attached the screenshot of dialog box which opens in the browser.